# «Довести до сведения всех о чем-то» или «довести для сведения что-то» — как правильно?

Tags: падежи

«Довести до сведения всех о чем-то» или «довести для сведения что-то» — как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

> **Све́дение**, -я, ср.
> ...
> В некоторых сочетаниях: знание, представление о чём-н. *Принять к
> сведению (узнав, усвоить). **Довести до чьего-н. сведения (сообщить,
> уведомить). Довести что-н. до всеобщего сведения (сделать известным
> всем).***
> [Толковый словарь Ожегова C. И.]

Правильно: *«довести до сведения что-нибудь»* (сообщить, уведомить) и *«довести что-нибудь до всеобщего сведения»* (сделать известным всем).

> **Довести** (в разных значениях) кого-что до чего.
> *Возьмешься ли ты
> довести меня до ночлега? (Пушкин). Довести дорогу до районного центра.
> Я все не теряю надежды довести скорость передвижения до сорока верст
> (Гарин-Михайловский). ...Он очень скоро довел ее до слез (Тургенев).*
> [Пунктуация и управление в русском языке Д.Э. Розенталь]

Правильно: *«довести что-нибудь до чьего-то сведения»*. Варианты: *«довести о чем-то»* и *«довести для сведения»* — неправильное управление.

«Всех» — родительный падеж от «все», поэтому грамматически правильно: *«довести что-нибудь до сведения всех»* (сообщить всем, уведомить всех), но лучше звучит *«довести что-нибудь до всеобщего сведения»* (сделать известным всем).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, никто не будет спорить с корректностью фразы

```
Довести информацию ко всеобщему сведению
```

А тогда корректно и

```
довести для сведения что-то
```

потому что

```
довести для сведения что-то = довести до вас для вашего сведения информацию
```

А вот с нижеследующим есть сомнения

```
Довести до сведения всех о чем-то
```

Предлог **о**, как слово паразит, присоединяется ко все родительным падежам дополнений и изменяет глагольное управление на предложный падеж. Но проблема в том, что исходный глагол не всегда управляет предложным падежом.

> Под влиянием сочетаний типа: «подумать о чём-либо», «рассказать о
> чём-либо» — в речи частотно ошибочное использование дополнения в
> предложном падеже с предлогом «о» (о чём-либо) у таких, например,
> глаголов: «доказывать что-либо; поделиться чем-либо с кем-либо;
> коснуться чего-либо; подтвердить что-либо; объяснить что-либо;
> привести пример чего-либо; описать что-либо; признаться в чём-либо;
> подвести итог чему-либо; указать на что-либо».

Comment: *«Довести информацию ко всеобщему сведению»* — неправильное управление. «Довести до остановки транспорта», а не «довести к остановке транспорта». Можно **принят к сведению** и можно что-то **объявить**: *«— Ко всеобщему сведению, у нас на все пятьдесят минут! — объявил он и захлопнул за собой дверь. Дэмиан Диббен, Буря начинается, 2011»* Тут призыв ко всем принять что-то к сведению.

Comment: Довести можно как до остановки, так и к остановке. Но на ответ это не влияет, так как у нас в любом случае до. Проверяется так: Вести к остановке = > Довести к остановке

Comment: Я бы тоже _поспорил_ с приведенными в ответе примерами. Правильно _довести **до** всеобщего (или чьего-то) сведения_ (как и "до дому", а не "к дому", к которому "приводят"). **К** всеобщему сведению можно _сообщить_ что-то (вот что и т. п.) . _Довести **до** (не "для") сведения_ (чьего-то, кого-то - обязательно явное упоминание) можно _такую-то информацию_ (что так-то и так-то). **Для** (чьего-то) сведения _сообщают_.

Comment: Давайте начнем с чего-нибудь попроще. 1. "Довести к остановке" по вашему корректно или нет? 2. "Довести до него для его сведения" по вашему корректно или нет?

Comment: Предлог «до» обозначает предел. «Довести до остановки» — до остановки проводил и всё, в транспорт уже не сел с кем-то. У приставки «до-» аналогичное значение. Потому «**до**вести **до** …». В «вести к остановке» предлог «к» означает направление движения. Можно вести **к** остановке, но не довести **до** остановки.

Comment: Дело не в предлогах, а в совершенном/несовершенном виде глагола. Все что можно делать с несовершенным видом глагола, можно и с совершенным. 
Можно вести до остановки.  Можно вести к остановке. Значит можно и довести к остановке.

Comment: Я понимаю так, что «сведение» в данном случае, это совокупность знаний, которые у кото-то есть в памяти. **До**вести до сведения, это сделать так, чтоб новая информация **до**стигла сознания человека и стала частью того, что ему известно.

Comment: Сведение в данном случае это осведомленность/кругозор/знание. Можно подставить одно в другое и удостовериться в точности ответа.

Comment: "Довел к победе" не говорят, но управление у глагола не меняется при навешивании на него приставок. Что "Привел к победе", что "довел к победе" совершенно корректные фразы с точки зрения управления глаголов.

Comment: *«Все что можно делать с несовершенным видом глагола, можно и с совершенным».* Несовершенный вид «доводить до», совершенный «довести до». А у «вести» немножко другой смысл, более общий.

Comment: Мой тезис, что управление глагола не зависит от навешивания на него приставок, так как приставки дело наживное, а управление это что-то более фундаментальное. Сравните: Вел, вел и наконец довел (к/до) победе. Что вы выберете? Даже Розенталь не стал бы настаивать на выборе

Comment: У довести несовершенный вид доводить, однако у вести совершенный вид довести, так бывает :)

Comment: Хотя сейчас поподставлял другие глаголы в эту схемку, и она перестала работать- уж слишком общая. Ну что же, все равно проскакивают фразы типа "довезти в аэропорт вещи." итд. Можно доказывать их корректность так: "Куда вас довезти?" -"В аэропорт" == "довезти в аэропорт"